# How to add csrf token to angular 2 application

Tags: angular, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection, spring-restcontroller

I have enabled the CSRF in the java back-end (in **SecurityConfig.java** file)   due to maintain user sessions between the angular2 and spring app. but when the post submission fired, I haven't seen any CSRF token binded to the POST request.

[image]

How would be possible way to add the **CSRF** token to my **angular2** app.
(add to the post request )

---

loginService.ts

```
  userLogin(loginDTO){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    var result = this._http.post(this._rest_service_login, JSON.stringify(loginDTO),options)
        .map(res => res.json());
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You should have a look at the [developer guide of Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xsrf). You can implement a strategy (or use an existing one) by using providers.

#### RC.5

```
@NgModule({
 (...) 
    providers: 
    [
        { provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name')},
    ]
}) 
export class AppModule { }
```

#### RC.4

```
bootstrap(
    AppComponent,
    [
        { provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name')},
    ]
);
```

You can also implement a custom strategy for your application by using the following provider `{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useClass: MyXSRFStrategy}`.

Comment: Where to add the above mentioned options @Nicolas?

Comment: In the module providers, I have add details in the answer

Comment: Below component does not work with me.
Im using RC4.
=====================================================
                                                                  
**`@Component({
 providers: [
  {provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name')}, 
  {provide: XSRFStrategy, useClass: MyXSRFStrategy}
] })`**

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux I'm getting this error  
`"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found"`

Comment: I have made an edit for RC.4. @GauravRam What strategy do you use ? Are you sure your server side is working correctly ?

Comment: @GauravRam above segment not  working n RC.0 or RC.1

Comment: @NicolasHenneaux am using RC.5 strategy like how you mentioned above. Yes, the server is working fine. Once page starts it works fine for GET request and after when I EDIT, POST or DELETE something from the list I get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

You may have `CookieXSRFStrategy: Calling function 'CookieXSRFStrategy', function calls are not supported` while using  `new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name')}` directly. Use a factory to avoid this error like below :

```
@NgModule({
 (...) 
    providers: 
    [
        { provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: xsrfFactory},
    ]
}) 
export class AppModule { }

export function xsrfFactory() {
    return new CookieXSRFStrategy('myCookieName', 'My-Header-Name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you read the cookie value(default "XSRF-TOKEN") in JavaScript by below?

```
document.cookie
```

(not developer tool.)

if it can't read,you maybe mistake how to set the cookie.

cookie path must be set root("/") like below.

```
cookie.setPath("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was on the back side (as correctly pointed out [harufumi.abe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8058753/harufumi-abe)) - my cookies came with a path */my-domain* instead of */*.
After adding the setting on the backend (spring boot 2.0)

```
# Path of the session cookie.
server.servlet.session.cookie.path=/
```

everything began to work out of the box.